# Batch Variable Value Check Range?

Tags: variables, batch-file, comparison, range

looking to do a range comparison of the value of a variable, what would be the correct syntax to say

```
if %VAR1% GEQ 7 AND LSS 22
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest/compose the if conditions like this:

```
if %VAR1% GEQ 7 if %VAR1% LSS 22  echo yep
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not a "correct syntax" because there is not AND/OR operators in Batch files. You may combine several IF's, but this cause problems if you want to use an ELSE part...

Another possibility is to combine numeric values in a SET /A command that give an *equivalent result* of an AND/OR combination. This method allows to combine *several* partial conditions in a single numeric result, so the use of an ELSE part is straightforward. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:next
set "var1="
echo/
set /P "var1=Enter a number: "
if not defined var1 goto :EOF


set /A aux=(7-var1)*(var1-22), test=0, test=(aux-1)/aux 2>NUL


if %test% equ 0 (
   echo That number is between 7 and 22
) else (
   echo The number is NOT in 7-22 range...
)
goto next
```

You may read a complete description of this method at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3493).